# How to find Specific area from database by latitude and longitude in php laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I want to return area name from  database by given latitude and longitude ( not nearby places ) if given latitude and longitude  in area A then return area A.

This is the area table structure:

[image]

I found some codes but its return nearby places

Comment: Your data describes points, not areas. The simpliest area consists of a point with a radius. Another option would be a rectangle described by two points. Or polygons...

Answer (score 0):

If you want the exact coordinates (no radius or nearby places), just do:

```
$village = Village::where('latitude', 15.501501)->andWhere('longitude', 32.4325101)->first();
```

Otherwise you can use the code you found for nearby places but reduce the radius to 100 merters (or less) distance, so it will only get one location.